How can I solve this gaussian integral analytically?
This problem I am getting for my work. A, B, C are some constants. When the integration range is finite how can I solve this?
I am having a problem with this integration
$$\int_{\omega_a}^{\omega_b} \int_{\omega_c}^{\omega_d} d\omega_1 d\omega_2 \,\, e^{-A\omega_1^2-B\omega_2^2 + C \omega_1 \omega_2 }$$
I tried with mathematica and python but could not find any answer. Is there any source or book with which I can get some help or anyone here to give me some hint.
Another one I could not solve is
$$\int_{a}^{b} d\omega e^{-A\omega^2+B\omega} \, erf(c+d\omega)$$
Is there any approximation on error function so that I can calculate this one?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

You're attempting to integrate the exponential of this function
\begin{align}
    (w_1, w_2)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}w_1, w_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}-A & \frac{C}{2}\\\frac{C}{2} & -B \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}w_1\\w_2\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
This would be very easy if the big matrix in the middle was diagonal because then you'd have a product of Gaussians you can split into two separate integrals you can do.
If you know a little linear algebra than you'll remember that you can diagonalize symmetric matrices (which this happens to be), which is how you solve this problem. Using the eigenvector/eigenvalue decomposition you find some new basis with variables $(z_1, z_2)$ which linearly depend on the $(w_1, w_2)$ such that the matrix is diagonal in this basis, then your problem is reduced to two integrals you can do seperately.
